# How to get the number of unique values for each layer in a Large raster stack in R?

Tags: r, stack, gis, raster

I have a large stack of raster which represent woodland patches (63 layers). I am trying to find a concise way of getting the number of unique values for each layer.

For one raster I have done this as below.

```
r1 <- raster(matrix(sample(1:100, 20), 10,10)) #create mock data
length(unique(r1)) #gives number of unique values
```

But if I had a stack of 3 rasters as below is there a concise way of getting this information for each layer.

```
### mock data
r1 <- raster(matrix(sample(1:100, 20), 10,10))
r2 <- raster(matrix(sample(1:100, 50), 10,10))
r3 <- raster(matrix(sample(1:100, 10), 10,10))
### create raster stack
allrasters <- stack(r1, r2, 23)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `freq` inside the `raster` package to obtain the frequency per pixel value for each layer and then just count the number of different values with `nrow`. Finally, you could transform the data from a list to a data.frame, in order to call it easier on further calculations.

```
library(raster)
as.data.frame(lapply(freq(allrasters), function(x) nrow(x)))

#    layer.1 layer.2 layer.3
# 1       20      50      10
```

Answer (score 2):

Example data

```
library(raster)
set.seed(1)
r1 <- raster(matrix(sample(1:100, 20), 10,10))
r2 <- raster(matrix(sample(1:100, 50), 10,10))
r3 <- raster(matrix(sample(1:100, 10), 10,10))
s <- stack(r1, r2, r3)
```

Solution 1: First get the *unique combinations* of values across layers, then the unique values by layer

```
u <- unique(s) 
x <- lapply(u, unique)
sapply(x, length)
```

Solution 2: loop over the layers like this

```
y <- sapply(1:nlayers(s), function(i) unique(s[[i]]))
sapply(y, length)
```

Solution 3: the suggestion by Jonathan V. Solórzano

```
sapply(1:nlayers(s), function(i) NROW(freq(s[[i]])))
#[1] 20 50 10
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to cast into a 3D array and use `apply`:

```
library(raster)
set.seed(1)
r1 <- raster(matrix(sample(1:100, 20), 10,10))
r2 <- raster(matrix(sample(1:100, 50), 10,10))
r3 <- raster(matrix(sample(1:100, 10), 10,10))
allrasters <- stack(r1, r2, r3)
apply(as.array(allrasters),3,function(x)length(unique(as.vector(x))))
[1] 20 50 10
```

This is not necessarily the question you asked, but incase this comes up for you, you can also apply into the stack of rasters using `apply`.

```
apply(as.array(allrasters),c(1,2),function(x)length(unique(x)))
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3     3
 [2,]    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3     3
 [3,]    3    2    3    3    3    3    2    3    3     3
 [4,]    3    3    3    2    3    3    3    3    2     3
 [5,]    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3     3
 [6,]    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3     3
 [7,]    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3     3
 [8,]    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3     3
 [9,]    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3     3
[10,]    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3     3
```

Comment: This solution works on smaller datasets, but may lead to problemns on large datasets that cannot be loaded into RAM